# CodeIgniter text to url

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

Can't find if codeigniter have any build-in helper to format string to url? 
For example "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" will be "lorem-ipsum-dolor-sit-amet" or something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifically, CodeIgniter has the `url_title()` method, which does what you're asking for. This method will remove all non URL usable characters.

```
$title = "Here's a string!";
$url_title = url_title($title);

// Produces: Heres-a-string
```

The documentation for this method (as well as the other URL helper methods built into CI) can be found [here.](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use built-in PHP functions. Here is an example:

```
<?php
$my_string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
$my_url    = strtolower(str_replace(' ','-',$my_string)); 
echo $my_url;
?>
```

Comment: Thought I had submitted a comment along with that; I think your method is too simplistic, sure for the example it works, but I think really it needs to cater for more than just spaces to hyphen. Other characters, apostrophe etc, very common.

Comment: @catachamonkey Hyphens were never a requirement. IF you re-read the question you will understand this.

Comment: You mean apostrophes weren't? Anyway, yes you solved the minimum asked, but he gave that as an __example__, he asked to format string to URL, the string could be anything, almost certainly more than just spaces need handling. Anyway, I've explained my down-vote enough I think.

Answer (score 0):

This one will help

```
$title = "Here's a string!";
$url_title = strtolower(url_title($title));

// Produces: heres-a-string
```